# Input range slider, replace thumb with image not working

Tags: html, css, slider

I am trying to create a custom range slider using css.

```
<style>
.slide-container {
  width: 300px;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  background: #DAA521;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  background: #DAA521;
  cursor: pointer;
}

    </style>
```

And the html:

```
<div class="slide-container">
     <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

I would like to replace `background: #DAA521;` with `background: url('{% static 'images/coffee.png' %}');` so that the thumb becomes a picture instead of just a coloured circle. However in practice, this doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the detailed `background-*` rules.

- `background-image: url('the url to the image')` - this is the image
- `background-size: contain;` - makes sure the image is always contained inside the button
- `background-position: center center;` - image is always in the center of the button
- `background-repeat: no-repeat;` - image is not repeated

Just use relative or absolute path to your static image, and drop the Django template code. It's generally not a good practice to include css into your templates, load them directly with the browser.

```css
.slide-container {
  width: 300px;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/344/average-2.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/344/average-2.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
     <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace background: #DAA521 with background-image: url("path to your image file");

Comment: Yes, thats what im trying but it unfotunately doesnt work

Comment: As per your question, you are using only "background" as attribute instead it should be "background-image" . also, why remove the percentiles inside the URL  and check once.