# I want to make a slider just like in the image but I am unable to make it

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a range slider just like in the image but the circle in the middle is not getting bigger than the height of the slider.

Here is my code:

```css
.range-slider {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1.5em 0;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 87%;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #eaeefb;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* background: url("images\icon-slider.svg"); */
    background-color: #10d5c2;
    border: 10px solid #10d5c2;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -407px 0 0 400px #a5f3eb;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-slider"> 

 <input type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" class="slider" id="sliderRange"> 

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62834173/input-range-slider-replace-thumb-with-image-not-working

Comment: The closing `"` of the class attribute of your input is missing.

Comment: I just created one, look if it does help.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yrf3bLz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The slider handle is clipped to the size of the slider bar because of the overflow property.

Remove `overflow: hidden` from the `.slider` css class to show it.

```css
.range-slider {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1.5em 0;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 87%;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #eaeefb;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* background: url("images\icon-slider.svg"); */
    background-color: #10d5c2;
    border: 10px solid #10d5c2;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -407px 0 0 400px #a5f3eb;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-slider"> 

 <input type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" class="slider" id="sliderRange"> 

</div>
```

Comment: If I will remove the overflow property then the slider background also becomes bigger. You just remove the overflow property and run the code you will understand what I am talking about.

Comment: My firefox is not showing the background at all. I would recomend to not use this chrome-slider but build your own. There are plenty of tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: hidden`

```css
.range-slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 87%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #eaeefb;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #10d5c2;
  background: #10d5c2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-slider">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" class="slider" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: If I will remove the overflow property then the slider background also becomes bigger. You just remove the overflow property and run the code you will understand what I am talking about